# 'TreeModule' does not appear to be an NgModule class after upgrade to angular 16

Tags: angular, npm, angular-tree-component

I am currently using @circlon/angular-tree-component 11.0.4 version and after upgrade to Angular 16, getting error 'TreeModule' does not appear to be an NgModule class.

I found that library is not compatible with IVY.

Can you let me know when this issue would be resolved to move forward

Can you let me know when this issue would be resolved to move forward